# JavaCC repetition ( ) *

Tags: parsing, lexer, javacc

I am using JavaCC to generate a parse.

As a token I am writing:

```
TOKEN: 
{ 
     < #LETTER : ["a"-"z", "A"-"Z" ] >
   | < #DIGIT : [ "0"-"9" ] >
   | < IDENTIFIER: ("_" |< LETTER >) ("_" | < LETTER > | < DIGIT >)*>
}
```

And as a (parser) method:

```
SimpleNode Identifier() :
{
  Token t;
}
{
      t=< IDENTIFIER >
      {
         String n = new String(t.image);
         jjtThis.jjtSetValue( n );
         return jjtThis;
      }
}
```

Hence this should accept _ only since the second part of identifier means 0 or more, but it only accepts _ _

Comment: What's the input? What's the exception?

Comment: i am inputting _ and the exception is: 
Encountered " "_" "_ "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting:
    <IDENTIFIER> ..

Comment: It looks like there might be a space in your input. Are you sure there is only one character in the file?

Comment: yes :( I am also doing 

    SKIP :
{
  " "
}

to skip if there is a space but it is not working

Comment: Remember that the first regular expression in the .jj file will win. So if you have another r.e. that match a single space, the first will win.